# Would past simple change the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: past-tense

> While drinking his tea, Billy **had realised** that the sleeping dog
> hadn't moved at all. The dog had been silent and motionless since Billy arrived. In fact, why would he have moved? He seemed to be so comfortable ! Finally, Billy reached out to stroke him. Actually, when he did pet him, he couldn't believe his eyes ... It was so unexpected ! The dog's back was hard and cold and when Billy pushed the hair, he
> could have seen the greyish-black and dry skin, perfectly preserved ... 'Good gracious ! It's fascinating ...', he exclaimed ... Billy told the lady that the parrot, in its cage,
> had fooled him too, when he had seen it through the window ! The landlady explained how much she  loved her little Basil and how she was glad to have stuffed him and kept him like all her other pets. Billy said he could have sworn Basil was alive ! 'That's because I stuff all my pets with passion, especially when their skin and teeth are so beautiful !...', she declared ...

"The Landlady" by Roald Dahl

I know that "had realised" means in this text that the action was completed, it happened before he thought that the dog was so comfortable but I was wondering if the author could have used "realised" .Would this change transform the meaning. I don't think so because the events are all in order

https://www.anglaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-anglais-2/exercice-anglais-104830.php

Comment: Billy couldn't realize the dog didn't move before seeing no motion, only after. So simple past would seem simpler: Billy **realized** that the sleeping dog hadn't moved at all. The dog **had been silent** and motionless.

Comment: what do you mean by simpler ?

Comment: Said "a thousand times"  here in this forum. It depends on what **you want to say** and not grammar. If one thing precedes another and you want to show that, use it. If not, don't. It is as simple as that.

Comment: The dog's stillness came first (had been silent), so Dahl could have said Billy realised [not had realised] that the sleeping dog hadn't moved. Still, I hate to criticize the classics by second-guessing them.

Comment: I think you might have a translation of a translation (from the original into French, then back to English). I don't believe Roald Dahl would write so badly. Why on earth would he start with ***Past Perfect*** here? I think at about this point in the original, the text is ***And suddenly, [he  realized](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22just+as+silent+and+motionless+as+the+parrot%22) that this animal had all the time been just as silent and motionless as the parrot***.

Comment: ...further in the cited text, I see *when Billy pushed the hair, **he could have seen** the greyish-black and dry skin...* Where the original says *...and when he pushed the hair to one side with his fingers, **he could see** the skin underneath.* Throw this garbage translation away! It won't teach you English - it's just some demented non-Anglophone teacher going nuts with Perfect verb forms!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the example text is a garbage travesty of English!

Comment: The story is "The Landlady" by Roald Dahl, which I've corrected. These words don't appear in that story, or at the link you've provided. Where is this quote actually from?

Comment: Using "had realised" might emphasise that it happened some time before the rest of the events, e.g. he finished his tea after the first sentence; or it's possible that the events in the whole paragraph happened before the rest of the story. But if it's not accurate there's little point asking a question about it or trying to figure out how it fits into the narrative.

Answer (score 0):

> While drinking his tea, Billy **realised** that the sleeping dog hadn't moved at all.

That sentence is correct.The meaning of the sentence is the same with the meaning of the original sentence.

Comment: It isn't wrong. Why do you say it is? Billy has now finished his tea. But it was during the course of drinking it that he realised that the dog hadn't moved. And now, after finishing the tea, he reached out to stroke him. Therefore this *is* talking about a thing that happened before something else.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi! You are right! I edited again my answer. Do you like it now? Could you please consider revising your downvote?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi! Thank you very for revising your downvote! I haven't managed to find a similar sentence with the sentence "While drinking his tea, Billy had realised that the sleeping dog hadn't moved at all". Could you please help me! I have never found a sentence in which we have two actions and the first action begins before the action which is expressed with Past Perfect and ends after the sentence which is expressed with Past Perfect .

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to find a similar sentence in a grammar book!